# How can I build this gradle project (KotlinParcelize) from the command line (Ubuntu 18.04, fail: Wrong plugin option format)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I found this article: https://android.jlelse.eu/yet-another-awesome-kotlin-feature-parcelize-5439718ba220 - and I wanted to look at the code there, https://github.com/burakeregar/KotlinParcelize.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and I thought of running `./gradlew` in terminal.

My Android SDK dir is in, say, `/path/to/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk` ...

So, I did:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ git clone https://github.com/burakeregar/KotlinParcelize.git KotlinParcelize_git
Cloning into 'KotlinParcelize_git'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 75, done.
remote: Total 75 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 75
Unpacking objects: 100% (75/75), done.
$ cd KotlinParcelize_git/
$ ./gradlew assembleDebug
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
.....................................................................
Unzipping //home/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.1-all/bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew/gradle-4.1-all.zip to //home/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.1-all/bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew
Set executable permissions for: //home/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.1-all/bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.8'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Eh, so a Java problem; my default is java 11, but I have java 8 too, so try that:

```
$ apt-show-versions -r openjdk | grep uptodate
openjdk-11-jre:amd64/bionic-security 11.0.8+10-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 uptodate
openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64/bionic-security 11.0.8+10-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 uptodate
openjdk-8-jdk:amd64/bionic-security 8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~18.04 uptodate
openjdk-8-jdk-headless:amd64/bionic-security 8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~18.04 uptodate
openjdk-8-jre:amd64/bionic-security 8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~18.04 uptodate
openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64/bionic-security 8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~18.04 uptodate

$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
```

Ok, try again:

```
$ ./gradlew assembleDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Right, so I do:

```
$ echo sdk.dir=/path/to/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk > local.properties
```

Ok, try again:

```
$ ./gradlew assembleDebug

> Configure project :app
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Observed package id 'build-tools;19.0.3' in inconsistent location '/path/to/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2' (Expected '/path/to/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk/build-tools/19.0.3')
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 in /path/to/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 not accepted.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Ok, so I run `/path/to/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk/tools/android`, install Build-Tools 26.0.2 (apparently the minimum version for the gradle version in the repo, and those build tools I did not have before), try again:

```
$ git add -f local.properties # so it does not get deleted by git clean

$ git clean -dxf

$ ./gradlew --stop
Stopping Daemon(s)
1 Daemon stopped

$ ./gradlew assembleDebug
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 5 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Observed package id 'build-tools;19.0.3' in inconsistent location '/path/to/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2' (Expected '/path/to/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk/build-tools/19.0.3')
Observed package id 'build-tools;19.0.3' in inconsistent location '/path/to/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2' (Expected '/path/to/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140321/sdk/build-tools/19.0.3')

e: Wrong plugin option format: null, should be plugin:<pluginId>:<optionName>=<value>

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
12 actionable tasks: 12 executed
```

If you run `./gradlew assembleDebug --debug`, you get a massive log of some 6400+ lines, which I pasted here: [KotlinParcelize_gradlew_debug.log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sdaau/043955c99a0360507c9c65f11dedfc90/raw/490e8d0c738cb4cf89ebe6b75e70a4f92fbe973b/KotlinParcelize_gradlew_debug.log), the only relevant part seems to be:

```
...
12:05:09.468 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: accepted socket from [127.0.0.1:26356]
12:05:09.469 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: (port 1757) op = 80
12:05:09.469 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: name = "[Ljava.rmi.server.ObjID;", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@3d7dbe2d
12:05:09.469 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: name = "java.rmi.server.ObjID", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@3d7dbe2d
12:05:09.470 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: name = "java.rmi.server.UID", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@3d7dbe2d
12:05:09.470 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: name = "java.rmi.dgc.Lease", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@3d7dbe2d
12:05:09.472 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: name = "java.rmi.dgc.VMID", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@3d7dbe2d
12:05:09.473 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: name = "[B", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@3d7dbe2d
12:05:09.488 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: (port 1757) op = 82
12:05:09.488 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: (port 1757) op = 80
12:05:09.521 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: (port 1757) op = 82
12:05:09.526 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: (port 1757) op = 80
12:05:09.526 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Task] e: Wrong plugin option format: null, should be plugin:<pluginId>:<optionName>=<value>
12:05:09.532 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: (port 1757) op = 80
12:05:09.533 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: name = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.report.CompileIterationResult", codebase = ""
12:05:09.533 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: name = "java.util.LinkedHashSet", codebase = ""
12:05:09.533 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: name = "java.util.HashSet", codebase = ""
12:05:09.533 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: name = "java.io.File", codebase = ""
12:05:09.534 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] [KOTLIN] compile iteration: app/src/main/java/com/burakeregar/kotlinparcelize/MainActivity.kt, app/src/main/java/com/burakeregar/kotlinparcelize/PersonModel.kt, app/src/main/java/com/burakeregar/kotlinparcelize/SecondActivity.kt
...
```

... but I still cannot understand - what plugin is in "Wrong plugin option format"?

Well, I'm stuck here .... How can I get this example to compile?

---

EDIT: few things I found:

- `e: Wrong plugin option format: null, should be plugin:<pluginId>:<optionName>=<value>` is apparently a message from `kotlinc` (I guess, the kotlin compiler), as noted in [KT-41303:
  CLI: "wrong plugin option format: null, should be plugin::=" with compiler plugins](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41303)
- So, it would have been nice to see when and how `./gradlew` calls `kotlinc` - however, not even `--debug` does not output such a command line, because "That's not possible. Simply, because most of the Gradle tasks do not invoke CLI commands." ( [How can I view the CLI command executed by a Gradle task in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314384/how-can-i-view-the-cli-command-executed-by-a-gradle-task-in-android-studio) )
- I tried importing this in Android Studio 4.0.1, and at a certain time, I got the message [Unsupported Modules Detected: Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56035306/unsupported-modules-detected-unfortunately-you-cant-have-non-gradle-java-modul/56123751) ; then I deleted `.idea` folder, reimported again - did not get that message anymore, but still same plugin null error
- Bit more digging in the debug log, it can be determined that the `compileDebugKotlin` step is the one failing, which can be triggered with `./gradlew :app:compileDebugKotlin --info` - but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally opened the project with Android Studio 4.0.1, and:

- Updated gradle in project to 6.1.1 (from the original 4.1)
- Updated to `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'` from 1.2.0
- Used kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 instead of kotlin-stdlib-jre7 (because I got a deprecation message somewhere)

... and now I do not get the "Wrong plugin option format" anymore - but now I get "Class 'PersonModel' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract ..." - which I'll ask a new question about.